# Would the next Mission Impossible be filmed inside the International Space Station?

Tags: mission-impossible

I kept on hearing that *Mission: Impossible* will be filmed in the International Space Station. Is there a truth to this? The next *Mission: Impossible* is a back to back part 7 and 8, so would this be for both movies or just a very short film?

Comment: I can't even remotely imagine any producer covering the cost of training and sending a whole crew on the ISS, let alone convincing the folks doing science work to give them the space for it. Who's your source?

Comment: @Jenayah [Surprised you didn't hear about this](https://twitter.com/JimBridenstine/status/1257752395750289409).

Comment: @F1Krazy o_O I didn't think this stuff could get even more expensive. Or rather I may have, but not for a movie and not directly, you know, the whole space thing

Comment: With Cruise being a licensed private pilot and with his penchant for doing his own stunt work, I can't wait to see him "pilot" a craft into docking aboard the ISS and performing eva's etc.

Comment: Something tells me you need more than a private pilot's license to be allowed behind the wheel of a space shuttle =P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Deadline](https://deadline.com/2020/05/tom-cruise-movie-shot-in-outer-space-elon-musk-spacex-unprecedented-in-hollywood-1202925849/)*, who first reported the story about Tom Cruise planning to shoot a movie aboard the ISS, stated (albeit without providing a source) that the planned project was "not a *Mission: Impossible* film". *Mission: Impossible 7* [had already begun filming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission:_Impossible_7#Production) prior to the announcement, and I can find no details regarding *Mission: Impossible 8*'s filming schedule at all, let alone any sources linking it to the ISS project.

So no, currently there is nothing to suggest that the film Tom Cruise plans to shoot aboard the ISS is a *Mission: Impossible* film. It's not impossible (pun intended) for it to be *Mission: Impossible 8*, but all the signs so far point to it being a completely separate project.

Comment: [not quite related] If you search details on the shoot for 7, you'll find a story from the Daily Mail in the UK that production moved from Italy to the UK, 18 March… which was actually the day the entire UK film industry closed down. The UK went into official lockdown the following Monday, 23rd. Some productions are starting back up slowly now, but I've yet to actually see one for myself, all my schedule is still on hold.

Comment: One more reason to produce your film off-Earth. ;-)

Comment: It would at least be pretty substantial isolation ;)